# How to prove that $B_{d_{H}}(x, \varepsilon) = B_{d}(x, \varepsilon) \cap H$.

Tags: general-topology

Let (X, d) be a metric space and H$\subset$X. ¿How can I prove the question above?

I’ve tried proving that the first set is included in the second one, but I’m not sure if I can say that $\{h\in H / d(x,h) < \varepsilon\} \subset \{a \in X / d(x,a) < \varepsilon \} \cap H$ just by stating that every $h \in H$ is also in X since H is a subset of X.

Also, I don’t know how to demonstrate the second inclusion to show that both sets are equal.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, $d_H$ is simply the subspace metric on $H$ right?

If that's correct then your initial logic for the first containment is correct. Since $h \in B_{d_H}(x,\epsilon)$, we have that $h \in H$ and $d(x,h) < \epsilon$. But this exactly means that $h$ is an element of both $H$ AND $B_d(x,\epsilon)$.

The other way, simply note that if $h$ is an element of the set $B_d(x,\epsilon) \bigcap H$, means exactly that $d(x,h)< \epsilon$  (because it is in $B_d(x,\epsilon)$) AND that $h \in H$. But this is exactly the definition of the set $B_{d_H}(x,\epsilon)$. Hence we have inclusion both ways.

Another way to think about it is to consider the definition of the subspace metric. It's the restriction of the metric on $X$ to $H$. I.e. $d_H = d \bigcap \big((H\times H)\times \mathbb{R}\big)$. This looks confusing, but it just shows that the metric $d_H$ is essentially the exact same as the metric $d$, so long as you are working 'inside' $H$. That's to say that by definition, $d_H(x,y) = d(x,y)$ if both $x,y \in H$. Then intuitively, taking the intersection of $B_d(x,\epsilon)$ with $H$ allows you to 'work inside' H, by restricting the set of values to be lie H.

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume $\epsilon$ is $1$ and fix an $x \in X$. By definition $B_d(x, 1)\,\bigcap\,H = \{v \in X\,\vert\,d(v, x) < 1\}\,\bigcap\,H = \{v \in H\,\vert\,d(v, x) < 1\}$. Here $d_H$ is the relative metric in the subset $H$ and hence $B_{d_H}(x, 1) = \{v \in H\,\vert\,d(v, x) < 1\}$ because $d_H$ can only be applied to elements in $H$. Now you can replace $\epsilon$ by any positive real value.